# Structuring my website with Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, model-view-controller, models, controllers

I am new to Ruby on Rails. I am trying to develop a website which has the structure as explained below.
I have  2 tables (say A and B).A has many B.I have models and controllers for these tables(say A_m,A_c and B_m,B_c).
My aim is to have different contorllers and views, for users and administrators.
So I have another controller (say X_c).

Will I be able to fetch data into X_C and its associated views from the 2 tables( 2 models)? 
Or is this structure completely wrong? 
What materials can I refer to, to be able to acheive this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fetch data from A_m or B_m in the X_C controller. Here is an example:

```
class XController < ApplicationController
    users = AModel.all
    other_table_data = BModel.where("field = 'value'")
end
```

All the models can accessed from any controller.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need separate controllers for admins and users. You just need to lock down access to certain actions via some authorization mechanism. [This site has a list](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/rails_authorization) of popular authorization tools that can help you do this.

Comment: Very nice. You can try `devise` (for advanced stuff) or `authlogic` (which is pretty simple to implement)